# EventListener keydown event not firing with multiple keys down

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When using `window.addEventListener`, with the `'keydown'` event, it stops working as intended when multiple keys have already been pressed.

This can be seen with the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
})
```

This will work for 2-5 keys, at which point further events are not registered. Is there a way to fix this problem?

I am trying to implement a system that keeps track of how long each key has been pressed down for (code below). If you can think of a workaround that would work with this system, that would be much appreciated.

```
let keyController = { //object containing information about keys;
    keyTimes: [], //time pressed, indexed by keyCode. undefined when not pressed
    keyPress(keyCode){ 
        if (!this.keyTimes[keyCode]){ //to ignore autorepeat
            this.keyTimes[keyCode] = Date.now();
        }
    },
    keyRelease(keyCode){
        delete this.keyTimes[keyCode];
    },
    getTimePressed(keyCode){
        return this.keyTimes[keyCode] ? Date.now() - this.keyTimes[keyCode] : 0;
    }
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    keyController.keyPress(event.keyCode);
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    keyController.keyRelease(event.keyCode);
})
```

Thank you :)

Comment: that's a hardware limitation of most keyboards - try holding down more than about 4 or 5 keys on many keyboards and you'll see that it's not a browser limitation - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#n-key_rollover - in other words, you need a keyboard with n-key rollover, and an operating system that supports "HID report protocol" in the case of a USB keyboard - PS/2 keyboards are more likely to have n-key rollover

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think this is the problem. I have implemented something like this in Java and C++ in the past, and I am able to player local multiplayer games with 3 people on my keyboard without trouble.

Comment: are you using exactly the same hardware (pc and keyboard) and operating system (same version) ... and you can get more than 6 keys in java/c++ but 2-5 in the browser?

Comment: @Jaromanda X I think so, but I might be mistaken. I don't have an easy way to test this right now unfortunately. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: easy way to test .... in notepad (or whatever is equivalent in your operating system) press and hold 8 keys - e.g. I just pressed `pqoweiur` but only `pqowei` was entered into this comment box ... hence, my keyboard is limited to 6-key rollover (I've yet to find more than 6 - but less is easy .. `1234` then `5` doesn't work, but `1234jk` does - `qwert` and then `y` doesn't work, but `i` does for example)

Comment: alright, yeah thanks I guess that was the problem. sad times